# Docker continuum/miniconda3 container not showing "conda"

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, conda, miniconda

I have a Docker container running the continuum/miniconda3 image with a Django project that is successfully serving to localhost:8000, and I can see my project running in the browser. The container is built with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /pft
WORKDIR /pft
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y && \
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev -y && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN conda create --name pft python=3
RUN source activate pft
RUN pip install 'django==1.10.5'
```

However, when I try and run the "conda" command in the running terminal with the following:

```
docker exec -it my_running_container /bin/bash
```

I am getting this error message:

```
root@ad9621c5e9bd:/pft# conda
bash: conda: command not found
```

What else is confusing is that in the Dockerfile the official image uses which can be found here https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/~/dockerfile/

An image is built with the following command, and I am not seeing  the either /etc/profile.d/conda.sh or /opt/conda.

```
RUN echo 'export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
wget --quiet https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.14-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
/bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
rm ~/miniconda.sh
```

I am sure that I am attaching to the correct container for one because I can see the mounted volume in the container, and for two I can see there is only one running container when I use:

```
docker container ls -a
```

UPDATE:

I am using a docker-compose.yml file which builds the container from the Dockerfile. I am not necessarily convinced that the container the compose creates is what I am thinking it is. When I use:

```
docker-compose up
```

It says:

```
creating some_container
Attaching to some_container
```

This is the Service I am trying to attach to. I am trying to attach with:

```
docker-compose exec -it web bash
```

The following is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
 version: "3"
 services:

   web: 
     build: ./config/src
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes: 
       - ./src:/pft
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
```

If I run the container based of the the image built with the Dockerfile via:

```
docker run -it some_docker_image
```

and I try to attach to it via:

```
docker exec -it my_running_container /bin/bash
```

When I change the command to run in the docker-compose file from

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

to:

```
command: source activate pft && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following error with docker-compose up.

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"source\": 
executable file not found in $PATH"
```

What is weird, is if I manually build an image and "docker run" a container based off that image using my Dockerfile, it works as expected. When I look up the image docker-compose automatically creates from the Dockerfile, and try to "docker run" a container from the image, it gives the errors mentioned above. Why is this image different than the image created with the manual "docker build" command?

Comment: Try this brute force thing `find / -type f -name conda` and show us the `echo $PATH`

Comment: In your host, does `./config/src` have the Dockerfile that you've shown?

Comment: Yes, config/src contains the Dockerfile the container is built from.

Comment: So access your container with this: `docker-compose exec web bash`, try your `conda` command there. I've tested your Dockerfile and it has the `conda` command OK.

Comment: It brings me into the container, but shows conda: command not found.

Comment: Can you please run the both command I've provided? (find and echo)

Comment: There is nothing returned by find / -type f -name conda, and echo $PATH returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: I insist with `./config/src/Dockerfile`. It seems that it is not the same that you've posted here (`FROM continuumio/miniconda3`, etc)

Comment: If you read through my "UPDATED" section you will see that when I start the container directly with `docker run` as opposed to `docker-compose exec` I am getting different results from the same Docfile. I do not even have another Docfile anywhere else in the project yet. Also, my container is correctly serving my Django project which it would not be able to do unless Conda was installed.

Comment: So, you only have this volume: `./src:/pft`. Maybe you have another volume overriding other directory?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks Robert, your hunch on an incorrect Dockerfile was right in the end because the image docker-compose was built using an old version of the Dockerfile. So while I had the correct Dockerfile in my project, it was the older one that was in use. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Oh.. simple solution then! You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. When you use docker-compose up, and you have changed anything in your Dockerfile that the docker-compose file uses to build the service and containers from, you will need to use :

```
docker-compose up --build
```

because docker-compose is going to use the previous image that was built. After, re-building the image I am now able to attach to the running container, and everything is working as expected.